# Change text size on tabHost

Tags: android, android-style-tabhost

I'm trying to do a tabHost with 2 tabs, its ok, but i want to change text size, I search a lot but I don't find anything without change all layout of tab, i just want change text size, not change background or anything like that, i add my tabs like this:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("photos_tab").setIndicator(getString(R.string.userPhotos)).setContent(R.id.tab2));
```

when I try to put a TextView in setIndicator its work and I can change text size but change everything, click, background and other things.. so I want to change only text size.

any ideas?

ps: I'm not extend TabActivity, so I can't change Theme in AndroidManifest or something like this. (I tried it before: [How to change the font size of tabhost in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788971/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-tabhost-in-android))

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, You can do that by getting the child at a specified position and getting its textview and setting the textsize of it.

```
 TextView x = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    x.setTextSize(25);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, its work very well, but have anyway can i do this when i setIndicator?

Comment: I tried using Html.fromHtml() but it didn't worked with tabWidgets, so for now the only option is set it explicitly.

Comment: @thamerhatem No. You have to do this after you added the TabSpec to the TabHost: `tabHost.addTab(tabSpec)`

Comment: It always returns a Null Pointer Exception. I couldn't find the textview. :( Help.

Comment: @princepiero, Sebastian is right, you need to use this after you add specs to tab host. And you have to do this for every tab.