# Change the text size in tab in android

Tags: android, android-tabs

I've been facing the issue of text size in tab bar. Below is the image,

[image]

And here is my code,

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTabChangeListener, OnPageChangeListener{  
    private TabHost tabHost;  
    private ViewPager pager; 

 @Override  
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
   tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);  
   pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  

   tabHost.setup();  
   TabWidget tabwidget=tabHost.getTabWidget();

   TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);  
   spec.setIndicator("Check In");  
   tabHost.addTab(spec);  

   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);  
   spec.setIndicator("Buddies");  
   tabHost.addTab(spec);  

   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);  
   spec.setIndicator("Recommendation");  
   tabHost.addTab(spec); 

   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab4);  
   spec.setIndicator("Feed");  
   tabHost.addTab(spec); 

   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab5");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab5);  
   spec.setIndicator("Last");  
   tabHost.addTab(spec);

   pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(this));  
   pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);  
   tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);  

 }  
    @Override  
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId){  
         int pageNumber = 0;  
         if(tabId.equals("tab1"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 0;  

         }

         else if(tabId.equals("tab2"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 1;

         }

         else if(tabId.equals("tab3"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 2;  

         }

         else if(tabId.equals("tab4"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 3;  


         }

         else if(tabId.equals("tab5"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 4;  

         }
         else
         {  
              pageNumber = 0;  

         }  

         pager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber);  
    } 

    @Override  
    public void onPageSelected(int pageNumber) {  
         tabHost.setCurrentTab(pageNumber); 

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {


    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {


    }
    }
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

I want whole text to be set in each tab, how can I do that?

I've been trying this code to change the text size and getting this result,

### code

```
 TextView x = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
   x.setTextSize(10);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width = 100;

   TextView x1 = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
   x1.setTextSize(10);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().width = 90;

   TextView x2 = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
   x2.setTextSize(10);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().width = 100;

   TextView x3 = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
   x3.setTextSize(10);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().width = 40;

   TextView x4 = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
   x4.setTextSize(10);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().width = 40;
```

### Image of result

[image]

But I want the output as this image

[image]

As per above image, my tab widget should be movable, how can I do this?

Comment: did you try shouldExpand from the library? https://github.com/LordZoltan/PagerSlidingTabStrip.Net/wiki/Using-and-customising-PagerSlidingTabStrip.Net

Answer (score 4):

```
TextView x = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    x.setTextSize(25);
```

refer the below link for more detail

[Change text size on tabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624175/change-text-size-on-tabhost)

[How to change the font size of tabhost in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788971/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-tabhost-in-android)

Comment: how can we change the width of each tab?

Comment: tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width = 50;

Comment: BlueG... Check my edited question, I want outout as I described.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the TabLayout and Viewpager instead, and set the tabMode to scrollable, see code below:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 app:tabMode="scrollable"
 app:tabGravity="fill"
```

Use this line in your tab xml and it will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also customize the text and background of a your tabs. See this blog for a very good [tutorial](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136) on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy wasy to do Just add style to ur xml file declare the size in which you want.

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabWidgetText</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTabWidgetText" 
    parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textSize">100sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">**strong text**</item>
</style>
```

Dont forget to add theme with style name in manifast file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

Use app:tabMode="scrollable"

Answer (score 0):

Just put the TabLayout inside a HorizontalScrollView:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                 android:id="@+id/tabs"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="MyTabLayout" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyTabTextAppearance</item>
```

```
<style name="MyTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
```

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/welcome_menu_icon_height_10"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/white"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorAnimationDuration="1"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabTextAppearance"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.casa))
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.fdr_dps))
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.loan))
```

You Just try it i hope it works

Answer (score -1):

```
<TabHost
     android:id="@+id/tabhost"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TabWidget
             android:id="@android:id/tabs"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             >

         </TabWidget>


         <FrameLayout
             android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="0" />

         <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
             android:id="@+id/viewpager"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
     </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>
```

Code:

```
for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(SM.getTheme_colour()));
    tv.setTypeface(font_k);
}
```

This code works for tabhost change text color, type face (font style) and also text size.