# How to make tablayout tabitem text size equal?

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried other StackOverflow answer
[How to make tablayout text size equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399013/how-to-make-tablayout-text-size-equal)
but it's not working in my case so I ask this question please help me out.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabslayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabBackground="@color/gray"
                app:tabContentStart="72dp"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/black">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/TAB_OPINION"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"/>

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/TAB_FUNFACTS"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"/>
            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Comment: ask me anything thanks

Comment: please leave an upvote if you're not getting to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making the tablayout scrollable does the work for me.

```
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
```