# How to Increase Tab Text Size in TabLayout?

Tags: android, tabs

I have PodCastTab....i want fully Display TabName???
am not Asking about TabHost??
TabHost and TabLayout are Different...
This is ScreenShot of Tabs

once see this my code :

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing the tablayout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home").setIcon(R.drawable.home_selector));

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("News").setIcon(R.drawable.news_selector));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Videos").setIcon(R.drawable.video_selector));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("PodCasts").setIcon(R.drawable.podcast_selector));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("More").setIcon(R.drawable.more_selector));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    //tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //Creating our pager adapter
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                bottombar.show();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                bottombar.hide();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                bottombar.hide();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 3) {
                bottombar.hide();
            }
            super.onTabSelected(tab);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabUnselected(tab);

        }
    });
}
```

this is Xml File

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activity.MainActivity">


<!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/shape"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:tabTextColor="#838587"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fafafa"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#fffeff"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:tabMaxWidth="250dp"
    android:minWidth="150sp"
    app:tabGravity="fill">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
```

[image]
how to display full Tab Text??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the text size in tab in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442084/change-the-text-size-in-tab-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through `TabLayout`

First you inflate your tab if not present, using

```
RelativeLayout tab = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater
                .from(MainActivity.this)
                .inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null, false);
```

and then you create a new tab and set a custom view using

```
tab_layout.newTab().setCustomView(tab);
```

Note that if you already have a tab (let's say you're working with a `ViewPager`), you can get the tab at a specific index instead of creating a new one by calling

```
tab_layout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tab);
```