# How can I set the titles of my tabs in a TabLayout to have the same font size?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-design-library, fragmentpageradapter

I am using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` with a `ViewPager` to create a `TabLayout` with 4 tabs. Everything is working fine except for the font size.

I have tried different solutions suggested in the following threads, but nothing has worked for me:

[Text size of android design TabLayout tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471177/text-size-of-android-design-tablayout-tabs)

[How to increase icon size of tabs in TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237896/how-to-increase-icon-size-of-tabs-in-tablayout)

[android font size of tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173080/android-font-size-of-tabs)

[Change the text size in tab in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442084/change-the-text-size-in-tab-in-android)

This is how my TabLayout looks like at the moment:

[image]

And these are my related classes:

> MainActivity.class

```
private void setupUi() {
    final MainPagerAdapter mainPagerAdapter =
            new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mainPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
}
```

> MainPagerAdapter.class

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static final String UPCOMING_TITLE = "UPCOMING";
    private static final String INTERESTS_TITLE = "INTERESTS";
    private static final String ABOUT_TITLE = "ABOUT";
    private static final String ACCOUNT_TITLE = "ACCOUNT";

    private static final Integer TAB_COUNT = 4;

    public MainPagerAdapter(final FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
        default:
            return new UpcomingFragment();
        case 1:
            return new InterestsFragment();
        case 2:
            return new AccountFragment();
        case 3:
            return new AboutFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TAB_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(final int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return UPCOMING_TITLE;
            case 1:
                return INTERESTS_TITLE;
            case 2:
                return ACCOUNT_TITLE;
            case 3:
                return ABOUT_TITLE;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

> toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

> styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingEnd">0dp</item>
        <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabLayoutTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TabLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/md_white_1000" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

PLEASE SAVE ME!

Comment: They already have the same size i thought.

Comment: why don't you customize your Tab with custom Layout

Comment: @Ibrahim If you look at "Account" and "Upcoming" the font size differs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
             android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextAppearance"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me! I somehow assumed the style was gonna be used by itself on the TabLayout..

Answer (score 1):

Possible Alternative.

app:tabMode="scrollable"

This makes titles of each tab of same font size. But at the same time tabs wont be fixed anymore.
But if you keep "fixed" tab mode, in phones with smaller width, titles look small or even go to next Line. So , tabMode = "scrollable" is better option for 4 tabs.

But still, if you need fixed tabs and same font size for each title, set the font size in style and make sure its small.
Example :

```
`<style name="MyTabLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
        <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item> 
    </style>`
```

Comment: The value of "auto" also worked for me, while also centering the tabs within the tab layout (If you don't want them moved to the start of the layout)