# Android: Change the font size in TabHost in Widget.Holo.TabWidget

Tags: android, android-tabhost, font-size, android-theme

I followed the answer from here: [StackOverflow: How to change the font size of tabhost in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788971/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-tabhost-in-android)

It does work, but I lose the Holo theme, and get an old default theme instead. So I tried the following:

```xml
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomHoloTabWidget</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomHoloTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <!-- Custom item for text appearance -->
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabWidgetText</item>
    <!-- End -->
    <item name="android:tabStripLeft">@null</item>
    <item name="android:tabStripRight">@null</item>
    <item name="android:tabStripEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:divider">?android:attr/dividerVertical</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">8dip</item>
    <item name="android:measureWithLargestChild">true</item>
    <!-- Following line results in ERROR -->
    <item name="android:tabLayout">@android:layout/tab_indicator_holo</item>
    <!-- End --> 
</style>
<!-- Custom text appearance item definition -->
<style name="CustomTabWidgetText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textSize">36sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
<!-- End -->
```

Essentially what I have done is edit the original definition of Widget.Holo.Tabwidget available [here@line:1801](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;hb=master) to include a custom definition for textAppearance.

I get the following error:

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:tabLayout'.

I just want to change the font size of the tab titles while retaining the Holo theme.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this once

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setTextSize(23);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Madhavi. This certainly works. I wonder whether there is a way to do it through xml though?

If I wanted to further customize the look of the tab (inheriting from the Holo theme), doing it in Java seems troublesome.