# Reduce the font size of title of tabs in android

Tags: java, android, tabwidget

I want to set font size of my TabWidget title. I have 6 tabs with the following titles:

> Delhi |
>   Mumbai |
>   New york |
>   Shahnghai |
>   Chicago |
>   Sydney

The screen is not able to show full text of title. Therefore, I want to reduce the font size of only title of the tabs and no where else.

Thanks 
Aman

Comment: Also Share you code with tab image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788971/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-tabhost-in-android may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `styles.xml` that defines the font size for your `TabWidget` and put the file under `res/values`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabWidgetText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabWidgetText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textSize">desired_font_size_in_sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then, specify the theme you just defined in your manifest file by adding the following under the `<activity>` tag of your tab activity:

```
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
```

This answer is actually borrowed from: [How to change the font size of tabhost in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788971/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-tabhost-in-android)

Hope this helps!